# Maximizing the inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, inverse, nonlinear-optimization

Take $\mathcal{X}$ to be a compact and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that all matrices $X\in\mathcal{X}$ are invertible.

I am trying to solve the following problem
$$
\max_{X\in\mathcal{X}} a^TX^{-1}b
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are column vectors.

I can of course compute the first-order conditions of this problem but I don't know if they are sufficient to characterize the optimum.

I am happy to impose more (non-trivial) constraints on $\mathcal{X}$ if this can lead to a characterization of the optimum.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As you pointed out, the objective function is convex, hence generic first order conditions to maximize a convex function will only imply a stationary point. Since you're willing to enforce more constraints, I would think the target should be casting the problem as a convex one, however I admit the since $X$ is your variable I have no ideas at the moment. Consider calculating the bi-conjugate of the function, which gives you the convex-hull of the problem. However I can't say that'll be easy too. Also assuming $X$ is diagonalizable, then casting $X^{-1}=QD^{-1}Q^{-1}$ and taking it from there